# Load div of and aspx page into the div of an html page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have and aspx page and an html page .

Now I want to load a Particular DIV from the ASPX into the HTML page .

Reason: The aspx page loads slowly , so I want the html (which loads faster) to display this DIV(which takes time to load )  from the ASPX

I have tried this with no luck

```
$('#htmldiv').load('../index.aspx #aspxdiv');
```

Comment: strange if you are loading the .aspx page inside a div it will take time to process that page (.aspx). And I don't think there will be any difference.

Comment: and there is nothing wrong which you have written. It's ok.

Comment: You are right, the reason for doing this is because the other elements on the html page will load first unlike the aspx page which will load the entire page only after the time consuming div has loaded

Comment: The only problem can be that the id of div changes at run-time. Have you written runat server on the div.

Comment: should i write runat server on the div of the html as well ?

Comment: no not at all it is not requried

Answer (score 0):

Make an aspx page that loads nothing but the div. Set the ajax url to this page, and your speed will go up. The problem with your approach is that the entire aspx page must be loaded before any response is recieved, so it takes just as much time as directly visiting the page.

Comment: excuse my noob question, but how do i how set the ajaz url ?

Comment: @user1749105 `../index.aspx #aspxdiv` is your ajax url. Change this to, for example `../divloader.aspx`, where divloader.aspx is a page that has nothing but your desired div on it.

Comment: I think the code is ok. $('#htmldiv').load('../index.aspx #aspxdiv');

Comment: @krshekhar Yes it is "ok", in that it throws no exceptions. You are clearly missing the point of the OP's question though. He wants to load the div *without* having to load the rest of the page. This is why he needs a separate aspx script that loads just the div.

Comment: @asad as far I know If you put the id of the container after the page name it loads that div only

Comment: @krshekhar That is wrong. The entire page is served by the script, then jQuery selects the relevant part from from this page and returns only this part. This means you always get the overhead of loading the entire page.

Comment: @asad Yes you are right. But it loads that part only. I want to say this only

Comment: @krshekhar The entire page is "loaded", but only the `#aspxdiv` part is kept. The server side script still takes the time to load the rest of the content, which just contributes to overhead and makes your ajax request take longer.

Comment: i just tried both methods and the html page loads entirely and the page still shows loading (im guessing the aspx part is loading ) for about 8-10 secs and still nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this line

```
$('#htmldiv').load('../index.aspx #aspxdiv');
```

The only concern is the path of the page or id of the page.
Either "../index.aspx" is not the correct path.
or "aspxdiv" is not the correct id.

Solutions:

1. Check for the path
2. chek for the div id which may have change at runtime

Comment: tried this method and now the html page takes longer to load but doesnt yet display the aspx div